# How to add association to relations, that are already created , through migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have created 2 table `students` and `issued_books`. but forgot to add `t.belongs_to :students` in migration, while creating `issued_books` table.

Now I have modified the corresponding model as:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :issued_book
end

class IssuedBook < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :student
end
```

How would I do it now through migration in rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ bin/rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
generates
```

will generate the following:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

So in your case it would be:

```
$ bin/rails generate migration AddStudentRefToIssuedBooks student:references
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to populate the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your `belongs_to` model:

```
$rails g migration AddForeignKeyToIssuedBook

#db/migrate.rb
class AddForeignKeyToIssuedBook < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_table :issued_books do |t| 
         t.belongs_to :student #-> student_id
      end
   end
end

$rake db:migrate
```

This will create the appropriate column in the `issued_books` db, which should allow you to reference its associated `Student` with it.

[Ref for `t.belongs_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421)

--

You should also consider looking up about [`has_many/belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) associations for scope on the table structure:

[image]